# Grouping and sum Quarter values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table in my SQL Server 2012 instance:

```
+---------+---------+
| Quarter | Values  |
+---------+---------+
| Q1      | 10      |
| Q2      | 15      |
| Q3      |  5      |
| Q4      |  1      |
+---------+---------+
```

I would like grouping quarter in order to sum values to obtain 
Q1 = 25
Q2 = 31
So, Q2 sum also previous values that exist in Q1.
If I had Q3 the sum would be Sum(Q1) + Sum (Q2) + Sum (Q3). 
In this way a simple Group by clause doesn't work.
Can anybody help me to find a solution in order to perform the described task using a simple select statement without using Union, please?

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you may need to change this query if you're dealing with multiple years.

```
--Setup sample table
DECLARE @MyData TABLE (
    TheQuarter VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    TheValue INT NOT NULL
);

--insert sample data
INSERT INTO @MyData VALUES ('Q1',10),
    ('Q1',15),
    ('Q2',5),
    ('Q2',1);

WITH Totals AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TheQuarter ASC) AS [QuarterIndex],
            TheQuarter, SUM(TheValue) AS [TotalValue]
        FROM @MyData GROUP BY TheQuarter)
    SELECT t.TheQuarter, SUM(tPlusPrev.TotalValue) AS [TotalValue]
    FROM Totals t
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Totals tPlusPrev ON t.QuarterIndex >= tPlusPrev.QuarterIndex
    GROUP BY t.TheQuarter;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SQL 2012, you can also use [RANGES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189461.aspx)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  TheQuarter
  , SUM( TheValue ) OVER ( ORDER BY TheQuarter RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS "RollingSum"
FROM 
  MyData
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc0e1/8/0)

**@edit:**

If you are dealing with multiple years, see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a6ca/1/0).